# TS (JS question) - Get 2 array of objects return 4 arrays - matches and unmatches from each one

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Interface -

```
interface I {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  size: string;
  location?: string;
}
```

Empty arrays -

```
let firstArrayMatches: I[] = [];
let firstArrayUnmatches: I[] = [];

let secondArrayMatches: I[] = [];
let secondArrayUnmatches: I[] = [];
```

Arrays -

```
const firstArray: I[] = [
  {
    name: 'daniel',
    age: 30,
    size: 'm'
  },
  {
    name: 'tamir',
    age: 30,
    size: 'm'
  },

]


const secondArray: I[] = [
  {
    name: 'daniel',
    age: 30,
    size: 's'
  },
  {
    name: 'ariel',
    age: 28,
    size: 'm'
  },
]
```

Create new map from second array (Ignore second string it's for something else in mt real code) -

```
const map = new Map<string, string>(
  secondArray.map(
    ({
      name
    }) => [
      name,
      'firstArray'
    ])
)
```

Run on first array -

```
for (const o of firstArray) {
  const match = map.get(
    o.name
  )

  if(match) {
    firstArrayMatches.push(o);
  } else {
    firstArrayUnmatches.push(o);
  }
}
```

Log -

First array -
`console.log(JSON.stringify(firstArrayMatches))`

```
"match: [{"name":"daniel","age":30,"size":"m"}]"
```

Second array -
`console.log(firstArrayUnmatches)`

```
[{
  "name": "tamir",
  "age": 30,
  "size": "m"
}]
```

Right now my function is able to return only matches and unmatches from the first array, how can I get the second array matches and unmatches?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will work only if there are no duplicates on the name of secondArray. (I hope it because you create a Map from it)

```
// create index of second array
const secondArrayIndexes = Array.from(map.keys());
// OR const secondArrayIndexes = secondArray.map(({ name }) => name);

for (const o of firstArray) {
  // get index of o.name
  const match = secondArrayIndexes.indexOf(o.name);

  if (match >= 0) {
    firstArrayMatches.push(o);
    secondArrayMatches.push(...secondArray.splice(match, 1));
  } else {
    firstArrayUnmatches.push(o);
  }
}
// finally secondArray become secondArrayUnmatches
// you should create copy first if you use secondArray after this
secondArrayUnmatches = secondArray;
```

Comment: Ty works great!. I do have a problem because you changed the `map` I did, I need to pass an object there. And with your sulotion I can't do that.
But it's my problem I didn't mention it in the question